# For what value of $f(x)$ the given integral equation have solution

Tags: integration, integral-equations

let the integral equation is

> $$\phi (x)-\frac{e}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}xe^{t}\phi(t)dt=f(x)$$

then

> 1).there exist a continous function $f:[-1,1]\to (0,\infty)$ for which solution exist.
>
> 2).there exist a continous function $f:[-1,1]\to (-\infty,0)$ for which solution exist.
>
> 3).for $f(x)=e^{-x}(1-3x^2)$ ,a solution exist
>
> 4).for $f(x)=e^{-x}(x+x^3+x^5)$ ,a solution exist

how to solve this question ,i can only solve simple questions in integral equations but this very tough ,

$\text{EDIT}$

After so much of reading of integral equation,i try to solve the question

$\textbf{the solution i tried}$-$$\phi (x)=\frac{e}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}xe^{t}\phi(t)dt+f(x)$$

$$\phi (x)=\frac{e}{2}x\int_{-1}^{1}e^{t}\phi(t)dt
+f(x)$$

$$\phi (x)=\frac{e}{2}xC+f(x)    \;\;\;\;\;\;\;....1$$ where $C=\int_{-1}^{1}e^{t}\phi(t)dt$

$\textbf{from (1)}$

$$C=\int_{-1}^{1}e^{t}(\frac{e}{2}tC+f(t))$$

$$C=\int_{-1}^{1}e^{t}\frac{e}{2}tCdt+\int_{-1}^1 e^tf(t)dt$$

$$C=\frac{e}{2}C\int_{-1}^{1}e^{t}tdt+\int_{-1}^1 e^tf(t)dt$$

further doing calculation i get
$$C=C+\int_{-1}^1 e^tf(t)dt$$

$$\implies \int_{-1}^1 e^tf(t)dt=0$$
after that i pick the option  'c' and 'd' and they satisfied the integral so they are sutiable for $f(x)$ and my option are also right but still don't know how to work for option 'a' and 'b'

please help.

Thankyou

Comment: For 1 and 2: If $f(x)> 0$, is it possible to have $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)e^{x}\ dx=0$? (same goes for $f(x)<0$).

Comment: Also, you have proved that the $f$ mentioned in (3) and (4) satisfy the necessary condition, this is not enough to show that a solution exists.

Comment: @aziiri then how can i solve this question, please give me hint,so that i can proceede further.

Comment: For 3 and 4: You have shown that $\phi(x)=e/2 C x+f(x)$. Plug this in the original equation and plug try to find a constant $C$ that satisfy the equation for the given function $f$ for any $x$.

Comment: i tried this ,but  still it  does not work.